# Retrieve the list of EMR clusters which have the autoscaling setup using boto3

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, boto3, amazon-emr

Using emr boto3 in aws lambda can I retrieve the list of clusters which have the autoscaling parameter setup or not? If its possible then which boto3 client should be used from this link. 
https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/emr.html#client

Answer (score 0):

Autoscaling is set on instance groups, not on clusters.

If you want to see all the instance groups' autoscaling policies, you will first need to get the [list of all clusters](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/emr.html#EMR.Client.list_clusters) and then [get the instance groups](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/emr.html#EMR.Client.list_instance_groups) of each cluster.

Notice that in the response to `get_instance_groups`, you get the `AutoScalingPolicy` value.